# Reducing execution time C++

Tags: linux, performance, c++11, optimization

### Task

You are given an amount of pages in a book. The book printer is lazy and will only print the side number on every other page. The first page number to be printed is 1. The task is to calculate the amount of times a specific number is used on the printed book pages. The goal is to print out all numbers used in bookpages being; 10^9 < pages < 10^12 in less than 5 seconds.

### For example

Amount of book pages is 20. The book pages to be printed are then, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17 and 19. The 1 contains only the number 1 and should therefor only increment the savings on 1 by one. However, the number 13 contains 1 and 3, therefor the number 1 and 3 will in the savings will be incremented and so forth.

### Question

How do I make the program execute faster at larger numbers? I've been thinking about using threads but I'm unsure if it's beneficial or not.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    long long sideNumber;
    long long numbers[10];

    if(argv[1]) {
        sideNumber = std::stoll(argv[1]);
    } else {
        std::printf("Please enter amount of pages.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) numbers[i] = 0;

    long long index = 1;

    while(index < sideNumber) {
        long long current = index;
        while(current > 0) {
            numbers[current%10]++;
            current /= 10;
        }
        index += 2;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::printf("%i : %i\n", i, numbers[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would start with using a bit of maths

Comment: The question is: given a sequences of successive odd numbers from 1 to `n` how many time each figure appear. Right ? I think it is a question for a forum of math.

Comment: At 10^12 pages, your current approach of considering each page will use at least 10^12 operations. Most processors nowadays are around 4GHz, or 4*10^9 operations per second. A quick division says that the fastest your approach can possibly be in this case is 250 seconds, a far cry from the desired 5s. Given this, perhaps you should be trying to find a way to avoid processing each page, rather than trying to speed up the process of doing so.

Comment: I think there is a recurrence relation on the number of digits. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

Answer (score 0):

This is trivially a maths problem, not a computing problem.
However, if this has really been set as a computing problem, then the answer is probably recursive.

Consider the page numbers 1-9. How many do they tally for digits 0-9?

Now consider the pages 11-19. Can you re-use the tally from the previous task to make a new tally? and again for 2x,3x,4x, etc.

Then, can you reuse the tally from 1-99 for 101-199?, etcetera.

Note that you need to think some more about how you deal with middle zeros.

Alternatively, you can use a pencil to get the same result in half the time it takes you to write the program.